# Signature of quadratic form on vector space of even dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Problem: Consider a real vector space $V$ of dimension $2m,\ m\in\mathbf{Z}^+$ and a non-singular quadratic form $Q$ on $V$. Suppose $Q$ vanishes on a subspace of dimension $m$, what is the signature of $Q$?

Attempts made: by Sylvester's Law of Inertia, choose a basis {$a_1,..a_m,b_1,..b_m$} such that the quadratic form is diagonal (up to reordering) with $p$ 1's, $q$ -1's, and n-(p+q) zeros on the diagonal. If it vanishes on subspace $U$ of dimension $m$, we let {$b_1,..b_m$} be a basis for $U$. We can characterise $p,q$ as the dimensions of the largest subspaces on which $Q$ is positive (negative) definite, but I am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Over any field, whenever $\dim(V)=2m$ and a quadratic form vanishes on a subspace of dimension $m$, the form is *hyperbolic* (and the subspace is called a Lagrangian). In that case, over an ordered field, the signature of the quadratic form is $0$.

A possible way to see this is to take a basis of a Lagrangian $L$, say $(e_1,\dots,e_m)$, and then choose some $f_i\in V$ which is not orthogonal to $e_i$, and is orthogonal to the $f_j$ for $j<i$ (try to think about why that exists).

Then if we define $W_i=\langle e_i, f_i\rangle$, we get an orthognal sum $V=W_1\perp\dots\perp W_m$, and each $W_i$ is an isotropic plane. Now try to see that an isotropic plane (which is necessarily hyperbolic) has signature $0$.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I just have a question about the signature of the isotropic plane. On $W_i$, we have that the quadratic form vanishes on $e_i$, so the signature is zero only if it vanishes on $f_i$ as well ($p-q=0\iff p=q=0$ as the rank is $\le1$). But that means $f_i$ is in the Lagrangian, so we do not have an orthogonal direct sum? Or does this depend on the quadratic form vanishing on a larger subspace containing $L$?

Comment: No, you have a wrong idea about how isotropic planes work. Remember that we chose $f_i$ specifically so it would *not* be orthogonal to $e_i$, so $(e_i,f_i)$ is not an orthogonal basis of $W_i$. It would be impossible, since $Q$ is non-degenerate, to have an isotropic vector in an orthogonal basis. Try to see that (in general, this is not specific to this exercise) a non-degenerate isotropic plane is always isometric to $\langle 1,-1\rangle$.